# Error in the following dart code in VS code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am working with my first flutter project. Anyone there to resolve my error which is being displyed by VS code after running the dart code?[basic dart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huftb.png)

Comment: run `flutter pub get` and `flutter run`

Comment: @Chance tried both but the same issue remains.  "flutter doctor" and "flutter run" worked very well in cmd and there is no installation or setup issue as well ,but still these errors are being displayed.

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: please share your code ----with log can't say what exactely problem is @rr_14

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've imported the `material.dart` package and then run `flutter pub get`.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Comment: Could you provide your code? It'll be hard to find the issue without it/